# How do I search a key or a value in a Nested Json object/array?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, json

Assuming I have JSON data response as follows below and a Search Input on my lightning component.

I want to search for a key or value and get a JS array of results.

For example :

Searching for "firstName" will bring results :

```
[{"firstName": "Tom"},{"firstName": "Maria"},{"firstName": "James"}]
```

Searching for "2" will bring results :

```
[{ "id": "2"}]
```

Data response :

```
{
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "photo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/735509975649378305/B81JwLT7.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova",
        "photo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3424509849/bfa1b9121afc39d1dcdb53cfc423bf12.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Bond",
        "photo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/664886718559076352/M00cOLrh.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Been trying few approaches - but couldn't get a recursion work for all nested elements.
This will work only on the first level keys :

```
  const givenPath = component.get('v.searchInput');
  for(let path in data) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(givenPath)) {
            newData = {
                [givenPath] : data[givenPath]
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: this seems more in scope with stackoverflow rather than SFSE imo, i would suggest you browse that site since this is a frequent questions and may already have an answer, or you can post a new question there.

Comment: I agree but since we have lightning JS this is a very fine line between the 2. the intention here is how to perform the recursive function in Lightning JS.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on a similar topic, i had to find all the attributes "attrName" in a JSON, maybe you can get ideas.
The article is [here](https://andreaparimbelli.net/how-to-remove-attributes-tag-from-json-in-javascript/#code)

I wrote a function like:

```
//JavaScript Lightning (Salesforce)
removeAttributes : function(obj){
   if(!obj instanceof Array && !obj instanceof Object) {
       return;
   }     
   for(var i in obj) {
       if(obj instanceof Array || (obj instanceof Object && obj.hasOwnProperty(i))) {
           if(i == 'attributes') {
               //delete obj.attributes;
               //**INSTEAD OF DELETE YOU CAN PUSH INTO THE ARRAY**
           }
           this.removeAttributes(obj[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

The code represents a recursive function, which accepts an object as a parameter (JSON is a JavaScript object) and searches for the various properties by checking all the Arrays and properties of the objects.

for each properties it is checked if it is an Array, an Object or if it is a parameter you are looking for ---> if (i = 'attributes')

I hope I have been helpful

Comment: you probably want to explain what it is your code does - as is, this would be considered dumping code as an answer which is normally frowned upon.

Comment: Thats helpful thanks! I've add a path variable as extra input which replaced the 'attributes' and placed this recursive function in the helper.js file => Works great !

Comment: Good! I'm happy to have been helpful